# svg hover overlapping elements in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, hover, z-index

I have a svg with some circles that should get bigger on hover, here is a snippet

**!This will not work in Firefox**

```js
var svgRoot = $('.svg-root')[0];

$('.bubble').mouseover(function (e) {
        svgRoot.append(e.currentTarget);
    });
```

```css
circle{
  transition: all 200ms;
}
circle:hover{
  stroke: black;
  fill: white;
  transform: scale(3);
}
.svg-root svg{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="svg-root">
  <svg class="bubble" x="50" y="50">
    <circle r="10"></circle>
  </svg>
   <svg class="bubble" x="70" y="70">
    <circle r="10"></circle>
  </svg>
   <svg class="bubble" x="90" y="50">
    <circle r="10"></circle>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

To avoid the other circles overlapping the one the mouse is currently hovering over, I used the append trick. That solves the z-index Problem, but it causes a different one. It seems that after appending the node, Firefox does not recognize the hover state of the cursor. The circles will not scale on hover in Firefox, but they will in Chrome.

I need them to scale on hover and to have the highest z-index while doing so.

Any solutions?